# "The system cannot find the file specified" after updating the nuget packages

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, visual-studio-2022, nuget-package-restore

The nuget packages of the project were upgraded to new versions and pushed. When other developer takes the latest and tries to build the project is not able to build it. Getting following error:
[image]

I have tried updating the visual studio, delete all bin and obj files, clean and rebuild. But no luck. Getting this error continuously.

We have multiple functions and .net core services. Only functions are giving this error not the .net core services.

Any solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try running the function project in any other IDE's or CLI?

Comment: I have tried only in Visual studio-2022 Version 17.8.7

Comment: Upgrade Visual Studio to 17.9 and run the function again.

Comment: No, upgrading to 17.9 did not help. I still see the error.

Comment: Run the same functions in other IDE's like VSCode or CLI and check if the issue still persists.

Comment: It was issue related to certificate. Its fixed after adding proper certificate. Thanks for your inputs and time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to missing certificate. Once after adding the certificate and rebuilding the application it started working fine.
The issue was there from last 3 days and finally the above solution worked.